# How to create a Postgres query that will generate a series with calculated values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query that I use to calculate returning customers (with more than one order)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) as order_count
        FROM orders
        WHERE shop_id = #{shop_id}
          AND orders.active = true
          AND orders.created_at >= '#{from}'
          AND orders.created_at < '#{to}'
        GROUP BY customer_id
        HAVING COUNT(orders) > 1
        ORDER BY order_count) src;
```

And if I want new customers (that have only one order) I simply change this line:

```
HAVING COUNT(orders) = 1
```

Now, how can I generate a series between 2 given dates that will give me the number of new and returning customers for each day between the dates?

Expected result:

| date | new | returning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 | 5 | 9 |

I have tried this but doesn't work at all (`error syntax near from` is the error I'm getting) and I'm not sure how to fix. Ideas?

```
    select *, return_customers
      from (select created_at, count(*) as order_count
      from orders
      where shop_id = 43
        and created_at >= '2022-07-01'
        and created_at < '2022-07-10'
      group by customer_id
      having count(orders) > 1
      order by order_count) as return_customers from generate_series(timestamp '2007-01', timestamp '2022-07-11', interval '1 day')
    as g(created_at)
    left join (
        select created_at::date,
                count(*) as order_count
                from orders
                where shop_id 43
                and created_at >= '2022-07-01'
                and created_at < '2022-07-10'
                group by customer_id
                having count(orders) > 1
                order by order_count
                group by 1) o using (created_at)) sub
order by created_at desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on your initial query w/o the `having` clause and conditional counts with [filter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES). `order by` in `src` is redundant too.

```sql
SELECT src.order_date as "date", 
       COUNT(*) filter (where order_count > 1) as "returning",
       COUNT(*) filter (where order_count = 1) as "new"
FROM 
(
  SELECT date_trunc('day', o.created_at)::date as order_date, 
         COUNT(*) as order_count
  FROM orders o
  WHERE o.shop_id = #{shop_id}
    AND o.active
    AND o.created_at >= '#{from}'
    AND o.created_at < '#{to}'
  GROUP BY o.customer_id, order_date
) as src
group by order_date;
```